# How make a popup work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to develop a popup feature when you click on an Image the image opens up as a popup. Here is the example 
http://soumghosh.com/otherProjects/natalierosscms/175-2/

Click on the first image and close it. Then click on the second image. The images are repeating. Any ideas what I am doing wrong? For some reason I am not able to post code here.

**JavaScript:**

```
$('.alignnone').click(function(){
    $('.overlay').appendTo('body');
    $('.overlay').show();

    var popImage = $('.projectContainer').show();
    var thumbHolder = $(this).parent();
    thumbHolder.css('position', 'relative');

    $(this).clone().appendTo('.projectContainer');
    var cssAtrOne = {
        padding:'10px',
        width:'110%'
    };
    popImage.appendTo(thumbHolder).css(cssAtrOne);
});

$('.closeButton').click(function(){
    $('.overlay').hide();
    $('.projectContainer').hide();
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<!-- clickable image -->
<img src="http://soumghosh.com/otherProjects/natalierosscms/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/T1Main.jpg" alt="T1Main" width="559" height="745" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-181">

<!-- popup -->
<div class="projectContainer" style="padding: 10px; width: 110%; display: block;">
    <img class="closeButton" src="/otherProjects/natalierosscms/wp-content/themes/twentyeleven/images/closeButton.png">
</div>
```

Comment: Why not use a LightBox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have this:

```
$(this).clone().appendTo('.projectContainer');
```

You're appending the image to the `projectContainer` without clearing the `projectContainer` first (So images just continue to build up each time). So what you'll need to do is clear out the previous images, then insert the new one.

But inside `projectContainer` is your close button, which makes things a wee bit tricker. There are many ways to work around this issue, but a straight-forward solution would be to introduce another `<div>`, `imageContainer` inside `projectContainer`:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="projectContainer" style="display: none; padding: 10px; width: 110%;">
    <img class="closeButton" src="/otherProjects/natalierosscms/wp-content/themes/twentyeleven/images/closeButton.png">
    <div class="imageContainer"></div>
</div>
```

Then modify your JS:

**Change JS:**

```
//REPLACE the contents of imageContainer, not append to it.
//$(this).clone().appendTo('.projectContainer');
$('.projectContainer > .imageContainer').html($(this).clone());
```

Something to that effect should work.

Comment: @Jace--This is the second time you solved my problem :-) you are the man

Comment: @soum Oh, true! The cloning divs questions :) Glad to help.